# Loop and create list using R

Tags: r, loops

Using R studio I would like to create a dynamic list using a loop. The loop is indexed by a and b, including another specification in the loop the structure is not anymore working and as result I get into the list only the last value. Below the code. Any suggestion?

```
mylist <- list()

vec_a <- c(1,2)
vec_b <- c(5,6)

for (a in vec_a) for (b in vec_b) {
  print(a)
  print(b)
  multp <- a*b
  print(multp)
  #mylist[i] <- multp
}

#solution not working
for (a in vec_a) for (b in vec_b) for (i in 1:dim(expand.grid(tau_c,HoR_c))[1]) {
  #print(a)
  #print(b)
  multp <- a*b
  #print(multp)
  mylist[i] <- multp #the list should contain the output for each iteration
}
```

Comment: In the first loop you have `mylist[i]` but `i` is not defined for that loop. In the second, `tau_c` and `HoR_c` are not defined.

Comment: Try using  ``` multp [i] <- a*b ```  because seems you are not saving the hole list but only the last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the list should be of length `length(vec_a) * length(vec_b)`. I would suggest simply using an iterator like:

```r
i <- 0
for (a in vec_a) {
    for (b in vec_b) {
        i <- i + 1
        # i <- i + 0 before edit
        multp <- a * b
        mylist[i] <- multp
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Idea, changing i <- i+0 with i <- i+1 in the loop works well

Comment: Lol woops I'll change it.